# how to create edit form using Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Hellow, I used laravel auth command and create users table to register users. now I need update user information in edit.blade.php file. how can I do this new for Laravel.
this is My user Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];





public function getAvatarUrl()
{
        return "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5(strtolower(trim($this->email))) . "?d=mm&s=40";
}

}
```

I need create UserController.php file and edit.blade.php file to update users.

Comment: Ok, that's cool. Did you start them already?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create another model called Profile and insert the new Users field or you make the modifications in the migrations and the new fields as shown below:

```
 protected $fillable = [
    'username', 'email', 'password','$newField1','$newField2',
];
```

Then u will be able to access this new fields from the user model.

I hope this helps.